# Using a model instance with django-crispy and a formset

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I've got a modelform_formset that I'm rendering with django-crispy. Inside the layout of form used I have the following:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('remove', css_class="inline"),
    HTML('{{ form.instance.user.get_full_name|title }} ({{ form.instance.user }})'),
    Field('is_admin')
)
```

Note the `{{form.instance}}` - That's not getting rendered properly binding. Is there a way to get the value for the specific model?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do this.  This captures the case where you don't have an instance :D

```
class XYXForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(XYXForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        label = "New Object"
        if self.instance:
            label = '{0} {1}'.format(
                self.instance.user.get_full_name.capitalize(), 
                self.instance.user)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'community_form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('remove', css_class="inline"),
            HTML(label),
            Field('is_admin')
        )
```

HTH

Comment: There is a problem with helper and formset - we can't use label in helper which is outside the ModelForm -